# Can you hook the opening of the DATA handle?

Tags: perl, perl-module

Can you hook the opening of the DATA handle for a module while Perl is still compiling? And by that I mean is there a way that I can insert code that will run *after* Perl has opened the `DATA` glob for reading but *before* the compilation phase has ceased.

Failing that, can you at least see the *raw* text after `__DATA__` before the compiler opens it up?

---

In response to Ikegami, on recent scripts that I have been working on, I have been using `__DATA__` section + YAML syntax to configure the script. I've also been building up a vocabulary of YAML configuration handlers where the behavior is requested by `use`-ing the modules. And in some scripts that are quick-n-dirty, but not quite enough to forgo `strict`, I wanted to see if I could expose variables from the YAML specification.

It's been slightly annoying though just saving data in the `import` subs and then waiting for an `INIT` block to process the YAML. But it's been doable.

Comment: What do you mean by "hook[ing] the opening"?

Comment: @JackManey, see revised question.

Comment: Hmmm...there's no way of doing that that I know of.  The closest thing that comes to mind is to have another script open up your original script (ie the one with the `DATA` in it), grab the lines after `__DATA__`, and then do what needs to be done before running the original script.  It'd probably work (depending on exactly what you want to do with reading the stuff after `__DATA__` before running the original script), but it's a bit hacky...

Comment: Does what you are doing have to happen at BEGIN time?  Could INIT or CHECK or one of the other blocks before runtime work?  If so, you could just add one of those anywhere and put your processing of the *DATA handle there.

Comment: @EricStrom, I tried `CHECK`, 'INIT` and even `UNITCHECK` blocks, but they didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that `::STDIN` actually gives me access to the stream `'-'`. And that I can save the current location, through [`tell`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/tell.html)`( $inh )` and then [`seek`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/seek.html)`()` it when I'm done.

By using that method, I could read the `__DATA__` section in the `import` sub!

```
sub import { 
    my ( $caller, $file ) = ( caller 0 )[0,1];
    my $yaml;
    if ( $file eq '-' ) {
        my $place = tell( ::STDIN );
        local $RS;
        $yaml  = <::STDIN>;
        seek( ::STDIN, $place, 0 );
    }
    else { 
        open( my $inh, '<', $file );
        local $_ = '';
        while ( defined() and !m/^__DATA__$/ ) { $_ = <$inh>; }
        local $RS;
        $yaml = <$inh>;
        close $inh;
    }        
    if ( $yaml ) { 
        my ( $config ) = YAML::XS::Load( $yaml );;
        no strict 'refs';
        while ( my ( $n, $v ) = each %$config ) { 
            *{"$caller\::$n"} = ref $v ? $v : \$v;
        }
    }    
    return;
}
```

This worked on Strawberry Perl 5.16.2, so I don't know how portable this is. But right now, to me, this is working.

Just a background. I used to do a bit of programming with Windows Script Files. One thing I liked about the wsf format was that you could specify globally useful objects outside of the code. `<object id="xl" progid="Application.Excel" />`. I have always liked the look of programming by specification and letting some modular handler sort the data out. Now I can get a similar behavior through a YAML handler: `excel: !ActiveX: Excel.Application`.

This works for me.

The test is here, in case you're interested:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use English qw<$RS>;
use Test::More;

use data_mayhem; # <-- that's my module.

is( $k, 'Excel.Application' );
is( $l[1], 'two' );

{   local $RS;
    my $data = <DATA>;
    isnt( $data, '' );
    say $data
}

done_testing;

__DATA__
---
k : !ActiveX Excel.Application
l : 
  - one
  - two
  - three
```

Answer (score 3):

The file handle in `DATA` is none other than the handle the parser uses to read the code found before `__DATA__`. If that code is still being compiled, then `__DATA__` hasn't been reached, then the handle hasn't been stored in `DATA`.

You could do something like the following instead:

```
open(my $data_fh, '<', \<<'__EOI__');
.
. Hunk of text readable via $data_fh
.
__EOI__
```

Comment: There are other possible workarounds, but you didn't state what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

I don’t know where you want the hook.  Probably in `UNITCHECK`.

```
use warnings;

sub i'm {
    print "in @_\n";
    print scalar <DATA>;
}

BEGIN       { i'm "BEGIN" }
UNITCHECK   { i'm "UNITCHECK" }
CHECK       { i'm "CHECK" }
INIT        { i'm "INIT" }
END         { i'm "END" }

i'm "main";
exit;

__END__
Data line one.
Data line two.
Data line three.
Data line four.
Data line five.
Data line six.
```

Produces this when run:

```
in BEGIN
readline() on unopened filehandle DATA at /tmp/d line 5.
in UNITCHECK
Data line one.
in CHECK
Data line two.
in INIT
Data line three.
in main
Data line four.
in END
Data line five.
```

Comment: Stoopeed StackOverflow syntax highlighter can’t even parse Perl.

Comment: The old package/namespace separator is spooky, and using it like that is just evil.  I wholeheartedly approve.

Comment: @mob, This isn't an instance where determining syntax requires running code.

Comment: `UNITCHECK` doesn't help me break enough rules. :). I mainly use `INIT` blocks for things that can't be handled in during compilation.

Comment: @Axeman I used to use `INIT` all the time, too, until I received a flamelesson on p5p for using it instead of `UNITCHECK`. I no longer recall the occasions under which `INIT` was unreliable, but I was convinced at the time.

Answer (score 2):

You can use any of the before runtime but after compilation blocks to change the `*DATA` handle.  Here is a short example using `INIT` to change `*DATA` to `uc`.

```
while (<DATA>) {
    print;
}

INIT {  # after compile time, so DATA is opened, but before runtime.
    local $/;
    my $file = uc <DATA>;
    open *DATA, '<', \$file;
}

__DATA__
hello,
world!
```

prints:

```
HELLO,
WORLD!
```

Which one of the blocks to use depends on other factors in your program.  More detail about the various timed blocks can be found on the [perlmod](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html#BEGIN,-UNITCHECK,-CHECK,-INIT-and-END) manpage.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid not, if I got your question right. It's written in [The Doc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html):

> Note that you cannot read from the DATA filehandle in a BEGIN block:
>   the BEGIN block is executed as soon as it is seen (during
>   compilation), at which point the corresponding **DATA** (or **END**)
>   token has not yet been seen.

There's another way, though: read the file with **DATA** section as a normal text file, parse this section, then `require` the script file itself (which will be done at run-time). Don't know whether it'll be relevant in your case. )

Answer (score 1):

[perlmod](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html#BEGIN%2c-UNITCHECK%2c-CHECK%2c-INIT-and-END) says:

> CHECK code blocks are run just after the initial Perl compile phase ends and before the run time begins, in LIFO order.

May be you are looking for something like this?

```
CHECK {
    say "Reading from <DATA> ...";
    while (<DATA>) {
        print;
        $main::count++;
    };
}

say "Read $main::count lines from <DATA>";

__DATA__
1
2
3
4
5
```

This produces the following output:

```
Reading from <DATA> ...
1
2
3
4
5
Read 5 lines from <DATA>
```

Comment: `UNITCHECK` would surely be better than `CHECK`.

Comment: @ikegami: Could you explain how `UNITCHECK` is better than `CHECK`? Is that a general statement, or applicable in the context of this question?